# Pressing enter submits wrong button

Tags: asp.net

I have two controls of type asp:ImageButton on masterPage. my login page contains a asp:Login control with two textboxes for username and password and a asp:Button for logging in.

If I press Enter after completing the two textboxed, it will trigger the ImageButton's method which refreshes the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the property `DefaultButton` to define, at the form level or inside a Panel, the button that will be "clicked" by default when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="btn5">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox0" runat="server" />
    <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btn2">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Button1" />
        <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="Button2" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBox2" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn3" runat="server" Text="Button3" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn4" runat="server" Text="Button4" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn5" runat="server" Text="Button5" />
</form>
```

In the example above:

- `btn2` will be "clicked" by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in `txtBox1`
- `btn5` will be "clicked" by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in `txtBox0` or in `txtBox2`

Comment: thank you. It works in my <asp:Login>  <fieldset> <asp:Panel> .... </asp:Panel> </fieldset> </asp:Login>.